# Why deleteCustomer function in Controller class is not executed when link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, spring-mvc, jsp

following functions are defined in **CustomerController.java**

```
    @GetMapping("/showFormForUpdate")
public String showFormForUpdate(@RequestParam("customerId") int theId, Model theModel) {
    
    // get the customer from our service
    Customer theCustomer = customerService.getCustomer(theId);
    
    // set customer as a model attribute to pre-populate the form
    theModel.addAttribute("customer", theCustomer);
    
    // send over to out form
    return "customer-form";
}

@GetMapping("/delete")
public String deleteCustomer(@RequestParam("customerId") int theId) {
    
    // delete the customer
    customerService.deleteCustomer(theId);
    
    return "redirect:/customer/list";
}
```

And **list-customer.jsp** file is following.

```
<!--  loop over and print out customers -->
            <c:forEach var="tempCustomer" items="${customers}">
            
                <!--  construct an "update" link with customer id -->
                <c:url var="updateLink" value="/customer/showFormForUpdate">
                    <c:param name="customerId" value="${tempCustomer.id}" />
                </c:url>
                
                <!--  construct an "delete" link with customer id -->
                <c:url var="deleteLink" value="/customer/delete">
                    <c:param name="customerId" value="${tempCustomer.id}" />
                </c:url>
                
                <tr>
                    <td> ${tempCustomer.firstName} </td>
                    <td> ${tempCustomer.lastName} </td>
                    <td> ${tempCustomer.email} </td>
                    <td>
                        <!--  display the update link -->
                        <a href="${updateLink}">Update</a>
                        |
                        <a href="${deleteLink}"
                        onclick="if (!(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this customer?'))) return false">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
```

When I click **Update** link, **showFormForUpdate** function in **CustomerController.java** is called.
But when I click **Delete** link, **deleteCustomer** function is not called and doesn't show any **WARNING: No mapping for GET error** as well. I tried this function after deleting **onclick="if (!(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this customer?'))) return false"**. But problem still remains.
Can someone help me fix this problem?

Comment: Your delete `a href` link is being overwritten by your `onclick` function.

Comment: but it still doesn't work when I remove onclick function.

Comment: @shinjw If I replace ‘deleteLink’ with ‘updateLink’, page is redirected to other page. So I think deleteLink has some problem. But I don’t know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I solved this issue. I can't pinpoint the cause of issue but I resolved by cleaning build and rebuilding.